# how to exclude items from List<RegistryPathData>

Tags: c#

I have a string array and a list and data is like below,

```
string[] str = new string[2] { "Prod1", "Prod2" };
        List<RegistryPathData> data = new List<RegistryPathData>
        {
            new RegistryPathData{AppName="test1", RegPath="Prod1|Version"},
            new RegistryPathData{AppName="test2", RegPath="Prod2|Version"},
            new RegistryPathData{AppName="test3", RegPath="Prod3|Version"},
            new RegistryPathData{AppName="test4", RegPath="Prod4|Version"},
            new RegistryPathData{AppName="test5", RegPath="Prod5|Version"},
        };
```

Now I want to exclude items from `List<RegistryPathData>` which is NOT matching with string array (prod1 & prod2). Need to exclude below 2, how to do this?

```
new RegistryPathData{AppName="test1", RegPath="Prod1|Version"},
        new RegistryPathData{AppName="test2", RegPath="Prod2|Version"},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List.RemoveAll()` function like this.

`data.RemoveAll(d => str.Contains(d.RegPath.Split('|')[0]));`

Comment: This returns an `int`?

Comment: Don't recall the return type, I think it returns number of items removed. I'll have to look up in MSDN or search in VS where we might have used it ourselves.

Comment: Ah yes - my apologies! `data` only has 3 values afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `.Where()` method to filter a sequence of values based on a predicate.

```
data.Where(d => !str.Contains(d.RegPath.Split('|')[0]));
```

This means filter out the items in the list where the string up to the first pipe character is not contained in the `str` array.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but maybe next time try to explain what the code in your answer does. It may seem self-explanatory to you, but it probably doesn't to the OP.

Comment: @GregaMohorko thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Where` method from LINQ and then check if any of the strings inside the `str` array match with the `RegPath` of the current object. Like this:

```
List<RegistryPathData> dataOnlyProd1And2 = data
    .Where(rpd => str.Any(s => rpd.RegPath.StartsWith(s)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Although this will work, it unnecessarily creates a new list while you can easily modify the existing one in place through `RemoveAll()`.

Comment: You can reassign to the same variable if you want to achieve that. Using LINQ methods has lots of pros later on and I prefer using them whenever I can.

Comment: You sound like you don't even know what you are talking about. `ToList()` will allocate a new `List`.

Comment: It will indeed allocate a new list (with the same objects), and it will at the same time discard the previous list. I know exactly what I'm talking about.